# loss of a DNS request

Tags: networking

UDP package are like once gone you will never know that it is received or not. So it is not gurenteed weather package will be received. I have learned that mostly DNS use UDP package to send the request. How does the loss of DNS requested using UDP are handled?

Comment: Timeout. You don't get a response in some seconds - it's either lost or never been sent.

Comment: DNS can use UDP or TCP. In fact TCP support is required for a DNS implementation. There was a misinterpretation by some people in the original DNS RFC. See _[RFC 5966, DNS Transport over TCP - Implementation Requirements](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5966)_, which clarifies that TCP is required: "_This document therefore updates the core DNS protocol specifications such that support for TCP is henceforth a REQUIRED part of a full DNS protocol implementation._"

Answer (score 1):

If no response packet is received within a certain amount of time, the request is re-sent. [Dan Bernstein suggests that most clients will retry up to four times.](http://cr.yp.to/djbdns/notes.html)

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to decide that a UDP datagram has been lost.  Neither is completely reliable.

- The most common is a timeout.  You send a message and wait for a response.  If you don't get a response after some amount of time, you *assume* that either the message or the response were lost.  At that point you can either try again, or give up.  It is also possible that the message or response is just taking a really long time to get through the network, so you must account for duplicates.  Note that all packet-switched communication, including TCP, works this way.  TCP just hides the details for you.
- Another method is to look for ICMP messages telling you that a packet has been dropped.  For example, `ICMP_UNREACH_PORT`, `ICMP_UNREACH_HOST`, or `ICMP_UNREACH_HOST_PROHIB`.  But not only are these messages rarely sent and subject to loss themselves, but you can sometimes receive them even when a message did get through successfully.  At best, if you get an ICMP message you can think of it as a suggestion of what might have happened.

Most DNS implementations use a short timeout because duplication is no big deal.  After a few repeats to one DNS server, it will try another one (assuming multiple servers are available).  Most implementations will also cache information about which servers are responding and which are not.